# Why does C++ use the name of the class for the ctor/dtor?

Tags: c++, syntax, dry

One thing that occasionally irks me about C++ is the repetition of defining constructors. This is especially true when defining the ctors in a separate cpp file. When we refer to them generally, we usually say "constructor", "destructor", "copy constructor", or abbreviate them as "ctor", "dtor", and "cctor". Even some C++ compilers abbreviate them like that. So why doesn't the language use that? Isn't:

```
class SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName
{
   ctor(int a, string b);
   cctor(const SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName& other);
   ~dtor();
};

SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName::ctor(int a, string b) { /* ... */ }
SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName::cctor(const SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName& other) { /* ... */ }
SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName::dtor(int a, string b) { /* ... */ }
```

easier to read than:

```
class SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName
{
   SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName(int a, string b);
   SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName(const SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName& other);
   ~SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName();
};

SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName::SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName(int a, string b) { /* ... */ }
SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName::SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName(const SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName& other) { /* ... */ }
SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName::SomeLongSelfDocumentingClassName(int a, string b) { /* ... */ }
```

?

Admittedly, I've been doing it the repetitive way for so long that the former block looks like nonsense at first glance. Is there a good reason Stroustrup chose the repetitious representation that just hasn't occurred to me?

Comment: Because the standard says so.

Comment: @manni66 Seriously? It's quite clear that the question is what's the reasoning that led to putting such a thing in the standard.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek Write an email to Bjarne then.

Comment: Obviously the question is not very practical, but it may be of interest to some. Feel free to ignore it.

Comment: It's been a long time, but Brian was asked this at Oxford some 20 years ago.

Comment: @BaummitAugen That would apply to most c++03 language questions. It could be that people other than the creator of the language know why language decisions were taken.

Comment: @juanchopanza But usually questions like this just lead to a bunch of guesswork and speculation in the answers. I think they are not useful.

Comment: @BaummitAugen That is on the people who decide to answer with speculation. They aren't forced to answer if they don't know the facts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes from the evolution of C++ as being "C with classes".

The C and C++ language committees (ISO these days) are always reluctant to introduce new keywords as doing that can break a lot of code. `ctor` and `dtor` would have been a new keywords. Note that `cctor` would not be additionally required since C++ supports function overloading; even if the very initial drafts did not.

Furthermore, being able to name a member function to be the same as the name of the class would be an exercise in obfuscation! Reserving it for construction and destruction therefore makes sense in this context.

Using the name of the class as the constructor with a `~` for the destructor was a sensible choice at the time. It still is, in my opinion at least.

Comment: This is a good reason. The class name makes itself a reserved word, but these abbreviations would take more potential names away. Although considering the standard rules (guidelines?) about who can and can't use leading underscores, 2/3 extra keywords seems inconsequential.

Comment: Using `~` is more than sensible. It's a fantastic pun. I recall reading that Bjarne chose to prefix the destructor with the negation operator, because the destructors job is to negate the work of the constructor. I'll see if I can find the original.

Comment: @MattChambers -- the class name is not a reserved word; it's an identifier.